# RewriteURL cause chrome Exception

Tags: google-chrome, iis-6, url-rewriting

I'm using FormRewriterControlAdapter to rewrite URL
But when I use Google chrome, I had a exception in
Exception:Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory
Stack Trace:   於 System.Web.Util.UrlPath.ReduceVirtualPath(String path)

my web site is http://ranking.heeact.edu.tw
and I've already added
genericmozilla5.browser
Google.browser
Yahooslurp.browser
from 
http://todotnet.com/post/2006/07/01/Get-GoogleBot-to-crash-your-NET-20-site.aspx

does anybody know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My got answer.
It's not URL rewriting problem. Just a asp.net control menuitem cause Chrome render html tag cuase exception.
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=7506cca26ec06af7&hl=en